# img Created Dynamically and Appended to a div also being Created Dynamically not being Displayed

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a "div" element dynamically with JavaScript and appending several elements to it. All the elements are being added properly at the exception of the image one, which displays only the "alt" attribute and not the image itself. What could be creating this issue?

```
 let div = document.createElement('div')
 // Elements are being properly added here
 var img = document.createElement('img')
 img.setAttribute('src', '../assets/Images/Image.jpg')
 img.setAttribute('alt', 'Image')
 div.appendChild(img)
 // Successfully adding more elements here
 document.body.appendChild(div)
```

ANSWER: This was actually due to vue.js, which I am using (and which I did not mention since I did not know that vue was the root cause). In vue.js, one must use a solution similar to what is found at this [link](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/vue+image+src+url+error)

Comment: Did you check if the path to the image is correct?

Comment: Yes, it is fine @Shuvo

Comment: Okay, can you provide a working example, so that we take a look into it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to also append the div using

```js
let parentel = element; // any parent element
parentel.appendChild(div);
```

Comment: Yes @Mafee7, I am appending it later in the code. Sorry, I haven't included everything for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

1.Append the div to the body of the document using
`document.body.appendChild(div)`
.

2.Check the path to your image

Comment: Thank you @ibraihm_317 I am appending it later in my code and the path is fine.

Comment: what is the way that your are calling this function with?